# How I can use Spotlight to search a USB flash drive?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, usb-flash-drive, search, spotlight

How I can search anything on a thumb drive using Spotlight?

As soon as I start to search it shows all content of my Mac's hard drive.

I am using Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Answer (score 3):

In the shell you could `mdimport /Volumes/SomeVolume && mdfind -name 'something' -onlyin /Volumes/SomeVolume/`

Answer (score 1):

Go into Finder, open the USB drive you'd like to search by double-clicking its icon in the file browser or clicking it in Finder's sidebar, and hit Command + F

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me ... searching for existing files result in empty list